Is the quadrupole tensor a $(2,0)$ tensor?
In classical electromagnetism, the quadrupole moment is usually written as
$$Q_{ij}=\int d^3r \rho(\vec{r})(3r_ir_j-r^2\delta_{ij}). \tag{1}$$
However, this represents the quadrupole tensor as a matrix. I have a few questions:

Is the quadrupole moment a $(1,1)$, $(2,0)$, or $(0,2)$ tensor?
How can I write the quadrupole tensor as a tensor?

To clarify, by a tensor I mean the mathematical notion of a tensor. I.e., given a vector space $V$, $T$ is a real-valued $(2,0)$ tensor if it is a multilinear (bilinear in this case) map $T: V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$. An example of such an object would be any element in the tensor product of two copies of the dual space $V^*$, i.e., $T \in V^* \otimes V^*$.
By inspecting $(1)$, it seems that $Q$ is a $(2,0)$ tensor. If yes, then can I more abstractly write $Q$ as
$$Q(\vec{v}, \vec{w}) =\int dV \rho \biggl(3\langle \vec{r}, \vec{v} \rangle \otimes \langle \vec{r}, \vec{w} \rangle - r^2I \biggr)$$
where $I$ is the identity $(2,0)$ tensor.

In Euclidean space, the distinction between all these types of tensors doesn't really matter, because you can trivially raise and lower indices. That's why physics textbooks never dwell on this point.

In other words, am I at liberty to write $Q$ as a $(2,0)$, $(1,1)$, or $(0,2)$ tensor? E.g. I could have written $Q(\vec{v} \in V, \vec{\alpha} \in V^*) = \int dV \rho\biggl( 3\langle \vec{r}, \vec{v} \rangle \otimes \vec{\alpha}(\vec{r}) - r^2 I \biggr)$. @knzhou

If you're being a mathematician, no -- you should give all 3 possibilities different names to avoid confusion about which one you mean. If you're being a physicist, sure, you can call them all $Q$. We don't care, because they all have the exact same components, so in a concrete calculation, it never matters which one you mean. That is why physics textbooks prefer to present tensors in terms of their components. They contain the physical content.

If you browse Math.SE, you can see numerous examples of undergrads thinking extremely hard about conversions between different types of tensors, taking $10$ steps and defining $5$ variables in order to do what a freshman physics student would do in a single step. So, as a general piece of advice, I would suggest not thinking about physics notation as "wrong" or "unrigorous" because it's different from pure math notation, and instead try to understand why we choose to use it. It essentially always works better for the things physicists want to do.

@knzhou overall good advice, but your first sentence in the latest comment is a red herring and has a flip side as well: on PhySE we have tons of questions which are very basic, simply because in physics the distinction between tensors vs their components, and just basic linear algebra concepts, isn’t emphasized, and too much emphasis is placed on coordinates and index manipulations (and also the language is more imprecise).

There is no ‘identity $(2,0)$’ tensor. What you mean is the underlying inner product. So, yes, the way you’ve defined it, $Q$ would be a $(2,0)$ tensor (normally I would write this as $(0,2)$, but whatever, you’ve defined something and stayed consistent with it, so it’s not wrong). But, as mentioned in the comments, there are associated $(1,1)$ tensors and also $(0,2)$ tensors. But their definitions  when written abstractly are of course different looking (simply because you’re on a different space).
Also, your final formula shouldn’t have a $\otimes$ symbol because you’re already evaluating on two vectors. So, the formula is $Q:\Bbb{R}^3\times \Bbb{R}^3\to\Bbb{R}$,
\begin{align}
Q(v,w)=\int_{\Bbb{R}^3}\left[3\langle\vec{r},v\rangle\cdot\langle \vec{r},w\rangle-r^2\langle v,w\rangle\right]\,\rho(\vec{r})\,dV.
\end{align}
(The $\cdot$ here is just multiplication of real numbers). If you want to write the abstract tensor itself, then you’d write it as
\begin{align}
Q&=\int_{\Bbb{R}^3}\left[3\langle\vec{r},\cdot\rangle\otimes\langle\vec{r},\cdot\rangle- r^2\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\right]\rho(\vec{r})\,dV.
\end{align}
(The RHS being an integral of a mapping $\Bbb{R}^3\to T^{(2,0)}(\Bbb{R}^3)$, taking values in the vector space of $(2,0)$ tensors).
